# Wordpress theme design: putting PHP in ("")

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, slider

I am fairly new to PHP, but have a general understanding, however I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I'm developing a WordPress theme and I've added the "Options Framework" from wptheming.com. I have a slider on the homepage that gets it's posts from a certain category, in this case category id 1. But the way the slider was coded means I can't place the code from options framework, which allows the user to pick a category, into the slider code which has the category ID hard coded in. I somehow am trying to find a way to merge the two. Below is the code:

This is the part in the slider that determines the category:

```
<?php
 $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
 $featuredPosts->query("showposts=4&cat=1");
 while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post();
 ?>
```

And here is the line of code (which returns a single number) I need to somehow get into the "&cat=1" part of the previous block of code:

```
<?php echo of_get_option('slider_cat_number', 'no entry' ); ?>
```

This may seem like a bit of a stupid question, but I am really stumped as to how to go about this!

Thanks, 
James

Comment: try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com in future

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure where to post this, so thanks.

Comment: Fair does, continue here and a moderator will no doubt move the question over when they come across it

Answer (score 1):

IF(!) I understand the question correctly and IF second function runs before first.

```
$x = of_get_option('slider_cat_number', 'no entry' );
 $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
 $featuredPosts->query("showposts=4&cat=$x");
  while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post();
```

Comment: That is the sort of thing I was looking for, so I think you did understand it, the only problem is, it doesn't work. It looks like it should though.

Comment: It works!!!! Thanks, just changed a little bit of code else where and it all clicked into place! Thanks for your help!